# R Why isn't the variance of the residuals equal to sigma2 value when using arima in fable?

Tags: r, time-series

I first fit an arima model to the beer dataset in `aus_production`.  Then I calculate the variance of the innovation residuals and compare it to the `sigma2` value reported from the model and they are not equal.  I would really like to know why they are not equal.  The documentation says that `sigma2` is the variance of the residuals.

```r
library(fpp3)
#> -- Attaching packages -------------------------------------------- fpp3 0.4.0 --
#> v tibble      3.1.5     v tsibble     1.0.1
#> v dplyr       1.0.7     v tsibbledata 0.3.0
#> v tidyr       1.1.4     v feasts      0.2.2
#> v lubridate   1.8.0     v fable       0.3.1
#> v ggplot2     3.3.5
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------------- fpp3_conflicts --
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()

fit <- aus_production %>% 
  model(
    ARIMA(Beer)
  )

(var(augment(fit)$.innov))
#> [1] 232.373
(glance(fit)$sigma2)
#>     year 
#> 241.2752

abs(var(augment(fit)$.innov) - glance(fit)$sigma2) <= 0.0001
#>  year 
#> FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If you want to know about programming issues, then you need to include sample data so that we can try to reproduce your results. If you want to know theoretically what would cause that, then this should be migrated to [stats.se], where it is more on-topic to discuss the theory around things like this. I suggest the latter, since it appears you aren't having an issue with the code itself. Do you agree?

Comment: Well the sample data is aus_production dataset from package tsibbledata included with library(fpp3).  I don't know if it's a bug because if I use another model like TSLM, ETS or a simple MEAN model the variance of the residuals does equal sigma2.  But the problem could be theoretic, so maybe I should ask it also in Cross Validated.

Comment: Okay, that is certainly relevant. Please realize that not everybody is familiar with all datasets included in the packages your explicitly list, and while the output suggests you have `tsibbledata` loaded, you really need to be explicit about that. This does not change my premise, though, that this is more a theoretical discussion. I won't push it though, feel free to wait. Your call.

Comment: `tsibbledata` is one of the packages attached by loading in `fpp3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residual variance (sigma2) reported by the ARIMA output is unbiased. To calculate it, you would need to take into account the degrees of freedom of the model.

The calculation used in `ARIMA()` is:

```r
library(fpp3)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.4.0 ──
#> ✓ tibble      3.1.5          ✓ tsibble     1.0.1     
#> ✓ dplyr       1.0.7          ✓ tsibbledata 0.3.0     
#> ✓ tidyr       1.1.4          ✓ feasts      0.2.2.9000
#> ✓ lubridate   1.7.10         ✓ fable       0.3.1     
#> ✓ ggplot2     3.3.5.9000
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()

fit <- aus_production %>% 
  model(
    ARIMA(Beer)
  )

# 5 observations lost to differencing 
# (1 seasonal = 4 obs, 1 non-seasonal = 1 obs)
res <- augment(fit)$.innov
nobs <- length(res) - 5 

# 4 estimated parameters with 1 variance estimate
npar <- 5

# Compute the unbiased variance of residuals
sum(res^2) / (nobs - npar + 1)
#> [1] 241.2752

# This matches the glance() output.
glance(fit)$sigma2
#> [1] 241.2752
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I've updated the documentation to be clearer about this: https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/commit/5fb2e121ae7257229147c65bd9bdad3a575d218e